# Send Copy of Order Confirmation email programmatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2, order-email

I want to send copy of order confirmation mail to another customer so for that i am using `btn_sales_order_save_after` event

and in observer construct i am adding

```
\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender $sender,
....
$this->sender = $sender;
......
```

And call method like this

```
 $order->setCustomerName($customerName);
$order->setCustomerEmail($customerEmail);
$this->sender->checkAndSend($order);
```

But it gives this error

> "Fatal Error: 'Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\IdentityInterface' in 'magento\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php' on line 73";

is this right way to send copy of order confirmation email?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look to this
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/135f967/app/code/Magento/Quote/Observer/Webapi/SubmitObserver.php#L40-L58

I think the right object is
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender;

and use the method "send"

In my case, checkAndSend was protected and I cannot use from external the class